# Phar archive outputs jibberish

Tags: php, apache, phar

I've created my first phar archive with the following code:

```
$phar = new Phar('myphar.phar');
$phar->addFile("index.php");
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub('index.php', 'index.php'));
```

The mentioned index.php only does a single output:

```
echo "I am in a PHP archive!";
```

When I run the above code, myphar.phar is created and when I run in at the cli, the output is "I am in a PHP archive!".
However, when I call the myphar.phar from a webbrowser, it prints some weird characters, like `????�???�?`, instead of my index.php contents and no error.

I added the following line to my apache httpd.conf to support phar archives:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phar
```

Does anybody know why it works on the cli, but not in the browser?

Comment: Weird. I cannot reproduce it, although I used your code and probably have the same configuration (I'm using PHP 5.3 and Phar 2.0.0-dev). What PHP and Phar version are you using? Are they up to date?

Comment: My PHP version is indeed 5.3.0 and I have the same Phar version. phpinfo() reports that phar is also a registered PHP stream.
I should mention that I'm using XAMPP on Mac OS X 10.6

Comment: Just wanted to add that this error is definitely in Apache configuration.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this problem lies in the

```
detect_unicode
```

setting in your php.ini.

There is currently a bug in PHP (http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42396) which makes __halt_compiler() not work correctly if detect_unicode is enabled.

So as a temporary workaround, set

```
detect_unicode = Off
```

in your php.ini. The price you have to pay is the inability to use unicode characters as the name of variables, functions and classes (they are still fine inside comments and strings)

Comment: This also happens if you `require('myphar.phar')` in a script run from  XAMPP's web server or PHP executable. If you don't want to flip the detect_unicode flag, the other workaround is to use `require('phar://myphar.phar')`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to view the source of the web page? Maybe you have somehow forgot to restart Apache after modifying httpd.conf.

Comment: The characters I described are the only thing returned in the source. I restarted apache multiple times.

Comment: Can you offer a download link for the `.phar` file? I want to try it on my machine.

Comment: Very weird. It's working fine on my machine. It's a Windows XP SP3. Don't know what else to say.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding of the phar file , you are suppose to open(fopen) the file in your php script which you are gonna be calling....if you are getting those characters back, it means apache is sending you the file in binary format....

if you add this "AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz .phar" to the apache config, it will make the file download-able like any other archive file and will not execute it like a php script

Comment: I don't want to download the file as a binary, but want to display it's contents